# Есть ли android x зависимость для navigation?

Tags: java, android, navigation-architecture

Вот решил попробовать поработать с `Navigation Architecture component`

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/

и не могу понять , что я делаю не так

Вот мой градл зависимостей

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

//android
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:${libs.supportVersion}"
implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:${libs.constraintLayout}"

//Stetho
implementation "com.facebook.stetho:stetho:${libs.stetho}"

//Crashlitics
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.5@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

//RxJava2
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:${libs.rx2Java}"
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:${libs.rx2Android}"

//Dependency Injection
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${libs.daggerVersion}"
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-rc02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${libs.daggerVersion}"

//Timber
implementation "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:${libs.timber}"

//Architecture components
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:${libs.lifecycle_component}"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:${libs.lifecycle_component}"

// Retrofit 2
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:${libs.retrofit2}"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:${libs.retrofit2}"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:${libs.retrofit2}"
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:${libs.retrofitInterseptor}"

//test
testImplementation "junit:junit:${test.junit}"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:${test.runner}"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:${test.espresso}"
}
```

все работает на `android x` зависимостях

Но если мы хотим попробовать поработать с навигацией нужно добавить следующую зависимость

```
implementation 'android.arch.navigation:navigation-fragment:1.0.0-alpha05'
```

и как только мы ее добавляем, то при компиляции получаем вот такую ошибку

> Error: Program type already present: android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver

Как мы знаем, `android x` не поддерживает использование библиотек `support`

а эта ошибка возникает именно по причине того, что где то в недрах этой зависимости используется `support`

Я начал искать в migrate файле https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor как заменить эту зависимость на `android x`, но там этого нет.

Вопрос как это сделать? Есть ли тут человек который пробовал использовать 
`Navigation Architecture component` вместе и `android x` зависимостями?

Comment: гугл говорит, что когда-нибудь [потом появится](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#navigation), а пока держитесь там .. вообще весь этот Х-проект еще в альфе, есть какая то срочная необходимость использовать все это прямо сейчас? это просто другие имена пакетов

Comment: @pavlofff нет конечно нет, просто эксперементирую))

Comment: @pavlofff, вроде уже не и совсем в альфе, у большинства  dependencies из androidx уже есть не только beta, но и rc версия

Comment: пока хоть один из пакета в альфе - весь пакет в альфе.